SQL Server change tracking?
I have an invoice module. There is a unit price on the invoice line.
I want to see the unit price change transaction list.
I can only get the last change.
How can I do it ?



Unit Price
Process
Date




500
First  Insert
...


502
Update
...


503
Update
...


604
Update
...


550
Update
...



I can only get the last change.
DECLARE @last_synchronization_version bigint;

SELECT
    CT.ID, P.GENELTOPLAM,
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, 
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS,
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT
FROM 
    FATURA AS P
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    CHANGETABLE(CHANGES FATURA, @last_synchronization_version) AS CT ON P.ID = CT.ID


Change tracking is not a history tracking feature, it's just for detecting that the change has been made. It will collapse multiple changes as well

Instead of CT (Change Tracking) could you be looking for CDC (Change Data Capture)?
